# onReady() doesn't execute $.getJSON() when browser restores a page

Tags: javascript

Let me state initially that the code below works fine when I open a new browser page and enter my web server's URL, and it works also when I reload a page (F5 or Ctrl-R). 
It only works partially however if I reopen a closed browser window and the browser restores my old tabs: then, the today's date is updated and displayed (see the code below, very simple), but the getJSON() call doesn't seem to be executed. The browser keeps displaying the data from the previous session. Only if I update the page (F5), the data in the browser window is updated.
I'm sure it's not the server. What else could it be?

Browsers: Firefox, Chrome, latest versions.

Using this code in index.html

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(onReady());
</script>
```

and this code in helper.js

```
var onReady = function() {
  // Display current date
  var dateText = moment().format("dddd, Do MMMM YYYY");
  var dateHTML = "<h2>" + dateText + "</h2>";
  $("#date-col").append(dateHTML);
  :
  :
  // Retrieve data from server and display it
  var statText = "Statistics:";
  $.getJSON("courses/starter", function(data) {
    statText = statText.concat(" " + data.count + " starter");
    $.getJSON("courses/dessert", function(data) {
      statText = statText.concat(", " + data.count + " dessert");
      $("#statistics").text(statText);
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass a callback instead of executing the function immediately.

Try:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(onReady);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> `$( document ).ready(handler)` expects argument to be a function expression which will be executed later when `DOM` is ready

In your example, you are invoking `onReady()` function and that function is not returning anything(`undefined`) hence exection will be like: `$(document).ready(undefined);`

Either use function expression like `$(document).ready(onReady);` or `onReady()` should return a function to be executed later.

Shorthand would be `$(onReady)`